# Write xls, pdf, and zip files to xml

Tags: java, xml

Current Java project I am working on a requirement wherein a XML file contains xls, pdf and zip files in node. These files are not a path to files in system rather data within node. Is there a predefined way of doing this? I didn't find any. What could be the safest way of writing these files as data in a xml node using Java? What we are attempting is to have a single data file, zipping is out of option as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to use base64 encoding to store the data in the xml node. Then you would probably want to have a mime type set on the node so the application can decode the data.

Comment: Thanks Owen!! I will give that a try... What other possible ways could be used other than base64?